# Anything similar to QSocketNotifier in boost::asio?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, boost, boost-asio

```
SOCKET sock = generate_socket("fileWizard");
notifier = new QSocketNotifier(sock, QSocketNotifier::Read, this);

connect(notifier, SIGNAL(activate(int)), this, some_slot(int));
```

The SOCKET is a win32 SOCKET, the function of "generate_socket" is creating a socket connect to a local exe which called "fileWizard"(don't know the implementation details of the function generate_socket).
With Qt, we always generate the socket and connect the signal and slot, but can't find a similar example in asio.

Do not familiar to socket and asio yet, please tell me what information you need. Thanks

Edit :

The purposes of the codes are monitoring the SOCKET, if there are any change of it, it will call the call back.

Similar to the example of asio([Daytime.3 - An asynchronous TCP daytime server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html))
The part which make me confuse is

1 : How could I transform the SOCKET to one of the boost::asio socket?

2 : How could I monitor the "change"(anything can read) of the socket(our seniors called it file descriptor)?By read_async?

Comment: Perhaps you could say what this all does. Win32 does have sockets, but they're not named (that would be Named Pipes, akin to UNIX domain sockets). Also, the line `connect(notifier, SIGNAL(activate(int)), ...` won't mean much to Asio experts that don't know too much about Qt. Perhaps you can explain what you want to _achieve_ rather than to pose impossible "translate this code for me" riddles with no context?

Comment: @sehe thanks for your suggestion and sorry for my ignorance.I do some edition, hope this could make my problem easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boost.Asio sockets support being created on top of an existing native socket through an overloaded constructor.  For example, [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload4.html) constructor could be used to build a `basic_stream_socket` on top of an existing native socket, such as a Windows `SOCKET`.
2. While Boost.Asio does not provide the direct equivalent of Qt's `QSocketNotifier` class, Boost.Asio does supports [reactor-style operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) by using [`null_buffers()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html).  Both approaches allow the application to be notified when an event occurs, such as when data is ready to be read from a file descriptor.  This event notification capability allows for each event loop to integrate with other event loops or third-party libraries.  For a complete example that uses `null_buffers()`, see the official Boost.Asio [non-blocking example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.nonblocking).